# Storyboard doesn't contain a controller with identifier 'MainWindow'

Tags: objective-c, macos, storyboard, nsstoryboard

I am trying to instantiate an `NSWindowController` from a storyboard in my OS X app:

`NSWindowController *mainWindowController = [[NSStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainWindow"];`

But this is what I'm getting:

`Storyboard (<NSStoryboard: 0x618000008500>) doesn't contain a controller with identifier 'MainWindow'`.

But in the storyboard:

[image]

It is set. No, there are no other storyboards. Yes, I've tried cleaning the project and the build folder, but nothing changes.

Why would I get this error?

**UPDATE:** I am building my app, coming back to the storyboard, and I see that Storyboard ID is unset:

[image]

How can Storyboard ID get unset by itself?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It was definitely a bug with Xcode. Restarting Xcode solved the problem.

Comment: When it happened to me, I noticed that the storyboard ID of the  window controller is gone every time I close the project and open it again. It must have been a bug related to the autosave feature. I manually saved the storyboard file and Clean - Build - Run. it worked.Your own answer helped me sir.

Comment: what more, this bug still exists in XCode 9.3 beta 4, nice job apple boys!

Comment: And still a problem in Version 10.1 (10B61)

Comment: it resets the id to empty every relaunch. Version 10.2

Comment: @KenZira I've been having the same issue. Have you tried the steps listed above?

Comment: This issue still exists in Version 10.3 (10G8)